# Google Maps taking minutes to return address

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using Maps API to return an address.  This was working fine, then sometime last week, w/o changing anything, it started taking 26 minutes to return an address. I traced it and found that after I hit the search button, it took 26 minutes for the Geocoder to be called, not that it was taking the Geocoder 26 minutes to retrieve the address.  I don't think this is a coding issue, but maybe something else that someone else has experienced.  I've included the code below.  I'm testing on a Samsung GalaxyTab 8 (SM-T550) Android: 6.0.1

Button setup in fragment:

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String address = addressEdit.getText().toString();
            //remove text from address
            addressEdit.setText("");
            //hide keyboard
            final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
            //submit address if one has been typed in
            if(address != null && !address.equals("")){
                //submit address to be found
                new GeocoderTask().execute(address);
            //submit the latlng of the marker on the map if not null
            } else if (latLng != null){
                address = getCompleteAddressString(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);
                new GeocoderTask().execute(address);
            //no address was entered
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.no_address_entered, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Geocoder class:

```
public class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {
    private static final String TAG = "GeocoderTask";

    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try{
            //return only 1 address
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.no_location, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Clears all the existing markers on the map
        map.clear();

        // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
        for(int i=0;i < addresses.size(); i++){

            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

            // get the string address based on the retrieved latlng
            String addressText = getCompleteAddressString(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);

            /* convert address from list into string
            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    address.getCountryName());
            */

            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(addressText);

            map.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Locate the first location
            if(i==0) {
                //map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
                //call dialog fragment to confirm patient address
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                //load latlng and string address google maps returns
                ConfirmAddressDialogFragment dialogFragment = ConfirmAddressDialogFragment.newInstance(addressText, latLng, patientName);
                //set target fragments and show dialog
                dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(MapFragment.this, REQUEST_ADDRESS);
                dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, DIALOG_ADDRESS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```